# How Can I Make My Child Item Resized Respect To Remaining Area On The Scaffold?

Tags: flutter, widget

I am trying do my Gradudation Project on Flutter and I am having hard time over Fitting Widgets.

Currently my screen looks like this

[image]

You can see from the screen shot there is a overflow in the element.

But When I work my widget with only **one widget on the Scaffold** It looks like this.

[image]

So I figure out I have not enough spaces remained at the end.

So I need to resize the element According to the remaining size on the Scaffold. My GridView code is here

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class RestaurantGridLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  const RestaurantGridLayout({super.key});

  @override
  State<RestaurantGridLayout> createState() => _RestaurantGridLayout();
}

class _RestaurantGridLayout extends State<RestaurantGridLayout> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Center(
        child: GridView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                crossAxisSpacing: 12.0,
                mainAxisSpacing: 12.0,
                mainAxisExtent: 250),
            itemCount: 10,
            itemBuilder: (_, index) {
              return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    color: Colors.white),
                child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Image.asset(
                        "assets/kofteci.png",
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "Title",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 8,
                      ),
                      Text("Description")
                    ]),
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can i modify this code for fitting the main screen. Note that my GridView has to be Horizontally Scrollable.

Comment: `GridView` is already scrollable, you don't need to wrap it in a `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: change the aspect ration on your `Gridview`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help you, remember that there is no single way to do things, only ways that work for you and that don't work for you.

#### Problem:

[image: Overflow image]

#### Possible solution:

[image: Pssible solution]

#### Code:

```dart
class RestaurantGridLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  const RestaurantGridLayout({super.key});

  @override
  State<RestaurantGridLayout> createState() => _RestaurantGridLayout();
}

class _RestaurantGridLayout extends State<RestaurantGridLayout> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 12.0,
          mainAxisSpacing: 12.0,
          mainAxisExtent: 210,
        ),
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) => const CardService());
  }
}

class CardService extends StatelessWidget {
  const CardService({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
        /// Or use Column
        child: Flex(
            direction: Axis.vertical,
            children:[
              /// or use Flexible
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  image: const DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('images/jhonacode_logo.jpg'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover
                  )
                ),
                ),
            ),

              /// Or just use this.
              /*
              Expanded(
                child: Image.asset(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  'images/jhonacode_logo.jpg',
                  fit:BoxFit.cover,
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                ),

              ),
              */

            const SizedBox(
              height: 60,
              child: ListTile(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                dense: true,
                title:  Text("Title", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),),
                subtitle: Text("Subtitle XXXXXXXX XX XXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow.clip,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12))

              ),
            ),

              /// Or if you like.

              /*

              const Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text("Title", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),),
                  Text("Subtitle XXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow.clip,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),


               */

          ]
        )
    );
  }
}
```

And you can use this widget easily.

```dart
Container(
   height: 370,
   child: RestaurantGridLayout(),
),
```

This way the widget will always have the space we gave it for the text and the image will automatically adapt to the available space.

I hope this gives you a general idea of ​​how you could implement it, or modify it according to your needs.